# Mostrar num select resultados da base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

Eu ja pesquisei sobre isto e nunca conseguia um código que funciona-se. 
Quando ponho o código não faz nada fica com uma só opção.

Eu queria era um código que desse para ver os dados num select

Código que eu estou a usar:

```
Serviço: <br>
<select name='servico' id='servico'>
<option>Selecionar Serviço</option>
<?php 
$sql_p= "SELECT nome_prod FROM produtos";
$query=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql_p);
$rows=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $rows[]=$row;
    echo "<option value=".$rows['nome_prod'].">".$rows['nome_prod']." 
</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o **mysqli_fetch_array** ?

Comment: ainda não usei o `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: o meu está como o de baixo agora, mas não dá nada na mesma

Comment: o `mysqli_fetch_array` não é a mesma coisa que o `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: A diferença entre os dois está basicamente na indexação do array.

Answer (score 0):

Use o `mysqli_fetch_object` direto para mostrar os resultados em formato de objeto.

```
Serviço: <br>
<select name='servico' id='servico'>
<option>Selecionar Serviço</option>
<?php 
$sql_p= "SELECT nome_prod FROM produtos";
$query=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql_p) or die(mysqli_error($ligacao);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
    echo "<option value=".$row->nome_prod.">".$row->nome_prod."</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Não dá. Eu não sei o porque de nao dar nada.

Imagem:https://imgur.com/a/tZLUwfm

Comment: adicione o erro na query `$query=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql_p) or die(mysqli_error($ligacao));` e veja se dá algum erro

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tZLUwfm dá isso

Comment: tente da forma que coloquei na resposta

Comment: por causa do `or die(mysqli_error($ligacao))` desaparece o resto que tinha quando ponho em comentário o que tinha saido volta, mas continua a mesma coisa não dá

Comment: Então veja se está printando algum erro dentro do select ou inspecione o código para acha-lo

Comment: eu posso mandar o código todo para si

Comment: Provavelmente algo esta errado na sua consulta ao banco. Tente executar sua query direto e veja oq retorna. Precisamos apenas do erro, nao do código todo

Comment: estou a dizer posso mandar para me ajudar a encontrar, que isto é uma inserção de dados